# Getting this Error: Server:: Write Abort: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: QueryClass

Tags: java

I have a JAVA server using MultiThread to communicate with client. Everything of the Server works, except for when a client object is send to Server thread. I have narrowed down the problem to this following lines of code.

The error is as a result of this line in the code: 
queryClass= ((QueryClass)inStream.readObject());    //Read data here
and QueryClass is a serialized class.

.Am getting the error above. QueryClass is another class, which i have it searialized: Here is my code.

```
public void run(){
   try{
    ObjectOutputStream outStream=new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream inStream=new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

         while(true){
       sleep(1);
       queryClass=  ((QueryClass)inStream.readObject());    //Read data here
       serverNotification.UpdateNotification("Performing .. operation for TaxOfficer");

    }           
}catch(Throwable thrown){
         System.err.println("Exception Caught : "+thrown+" deleting thread");

}
```

Comment: Does `QueryClass` implement `Serializable`?

Comment: The server application has the QueryClass in its classpath when it runs? And are you sure you obtain at server side a WriteAbortedException during a read operation?

Answer (score 1):

`QueryClass` must implement `java.io.Serializable`.  Make sure that its non-primitive, non-`String` members do as well.  Usually you don't have to do any work to implement the interface.  A good write-up is [here](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/JavaRMI_10/index.html?page=3).